# Setting a Larger Radial Gradient in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, radial-gradients

Currently, the radial gradient on Android is not quite what I am looking for.
I have a ball that changes radius and moves around, defined as:

```
private float ballRadius = 15; // Ball's radius
private float ballX;  // Ball's center (x,y)
private float ballY;
```

I want a gradient exactly this in green, but without the little white dot in the topleft:[image: Model Dot, from Blok]
Note the large amount of white space in the center, but a very dark color at the edge.

With my radial gradient code:

```
ballBounds.set(ballX-ballRadius, ballY-ballRadius, ballX+ballRadius, ballY+ballRadius);
paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
canvas.drawOval(ballBounds, paint);
```

I get an image with a little bit of white in the center: [image: Current Dot]

By doubling the gradient radius, one would expect the top image to show up.
However, this code:

```
paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(ballX, ballY,  2 * ballRadius, Color.WHITE, Color.GREEN, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

produces this dot, with washed out colors and the same size of whtie space in the middle: [image: Current Dot, Double Radius]
(sorry for the huge image!)

I even tried using an array of 3 white colors and 2 green colors and setting the change points myself, but I get essentially the same images as before:

```
    int[] colorArray = new int[4];
    colorArray[0] = colorArray[1] = Color.WHITE;
    colorArray[2] = colorArray[3] = Color.GREEN;
    float[] stopsArray = new float[4];
    stopsArray[0] = 0;
    stopsArray[1] = 0.9f;
    stopsArray[2] = 0.95f;
    stopsArray[3] = 1;
    paint.setShader(new RadialGradient(ballX, ballY, gradientRadius, colorArray, stopsArray, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

Do I have to import my own image?? Do I have to make a custom XML style?? Is there any way of making the gradient that I want?